# Using groovy ws with enum types?

Tags: wcf, groovy, web-services

I'm trying to use groovy ws to call a webservice. One of the properties of the generated class is it's self a class with an enum type. Although the debug messages show that the com.test.FinalActionType is created at runtime when the WSDL is read I can't create an instance of it using code like

```
proxy.create("com.test.FinalActionType")
```

When I try and assign a string to my class uin place of an instance of FinalActionType groovy is not able to do the conversion. How can I get an instance of this class to use in a webservice call? I've pasted the important part of the WSDL below.

```
        <xsd:simpleType name="FinalActionType">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="stop"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="quit"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="continue"/>
                <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can easily be done yet, not using the available WSClient API.

There was a suggestion to add a "createEnum" method to the WSClient class (see test case [patch](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/attachment/38859/createEnumAndTest.patch) and issue [GMOD-82](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GMOD-82)). Judging by Guillaume Alleon's comments under issue [GMOD-4](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GMOD-4), there should be a way to create an enum instance when WSClient 0.5.1 is released.

**UPDATE:**

As of GroovyWS 0.5.2 (at least, I haven't tried 0.5.1), enums can be used with GroovyWS as follows:

```
...
wsProxy = new WSClient(wsdlUrl, this.class.classLoader)
wsProxy.initialize()
def anObject = wsProxy.create("some.package.AServiceInterface")
def anEnum = wsProxy.create("some.package.AnEnum")
anObject.anEnumProperty = anEnum.AN_ENUM_VALUE
...
```